# When ag-grid react shows in dialog, columns do not resize

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I placed

```
      <AgGridReact columnDefs={columnDefs} rowData={props.jobProgress}        
        defaultColDef={{ resizable: true, sortable: true }}
      />
```

Inside a @fluentui/react Dialog.
It shows nice but the cursor for resize shows but doesn't resize the columns.
Any way to overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the below methods on `gridReady` event, to force the resize of columns!

1. [sizeColumnsToFit](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-sizing/#auto-size-columns-to-fit-grid)
2. [autoSizeColumns](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-sizing/#auto-size-columns-to-fit-cell-contents)

Comment: The issue is user want to resize, not size to fit or auto size. 
It works fine in Ag-grid that is not embedded in a dialog.

Comment: @OferGal just give `style={{ height:'100%', width: '100%' }}`

Comment: style={{ height:'100%', width: '100%' }} is already around the <AgGridReact